# How to "mix" differentiation under the integral sign with the fundamental theorem of calculus?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

The following function appeared before me today, and I don't know how to differentiate it: $$f(t) = \int_0^t h(s,g(t,s))\,{\rm d}s.$$ Assume that all functions involved are $C^\infty$ (or whatever we need to differentiate under the integral sign). My problem is that we have $t$ both in the integrand and in the integral. I could not write a composition to apply the chain rule. I don't know what the result is supposed to be, either. Can someone help?

Comment: Example 12a in Chapter 3 of [Elon's book](http://loja.sbm.org.br/index.php/colecao-projeto-euclides/curso-de-analise-vol-2.html) can help, where the author deals with the [Leibniz rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#Formal_statement).

Comment: I'll check it too, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $F(x,y)=\int_0^x p(s,y) ds$ where $p(s,y)=h(s,g(y,s))$. Then $f(t)=F(t,t)$. Now you should be set up to do your chain rule.